# laravel Route::resource() is using show() instead of create() at the /create route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Ok, I have a resource where the show($id = create) is taking over create()

The page I'm visiting

```
http://localhost/admin/packages/create
```

my error is: **Error**

```
ModelNotFoundException {#306 ▼
    #model: "Me\Subscriptions\Package"
    #ids: []
    #message: "No query results for model [Me\Subscriptions\Package]."
    #code: 0
    #file: "C:\Users\Me\Code\bb2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ImplicitRouteBinding.php"
    #line: 36
    trace: {▶}
}
```

my resources file: **routes/admin.php**

```
// I commented out every other line...
Route::resource('/packages', 'PackagesController');
```

My controller has all the resource methods populated... **PackagesController**

```
...

public function show(Package $package) {
    $meals = Meal::all();

    return view('admin.packages.show')
        ->with(compact('package', 'meals'));
}

public function create() {
    return view('admin.packages.create');
}

...
```

when I run **route:list**

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/packages                     | packages.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PackagesController@index                    | admin      |
|        | POST      | admin/packages                     | packages.store   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PackagesController@store                    | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/packages/create              | packages.create  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PackagesController@create                   | admin      |
|        | DELETE    | admin/packages/{package}           | packages.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PackagesController@destroy                  | admin      |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/packages/{package}           | packages.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PackagesController@update                   | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/packages/{package}           | packages.show    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PackagesController@show                     | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/packages/{package}/edit      | packages.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PackagesController@edit                     | admin
```

I've checked my **RouteServiceProvider** too...

```
/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
}

public function map()
{
    $this->mapAdminRoutes();
}

protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'admin',
        'namespace' => $this->adminNamespace,
        'prefix' => 'admin',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/admin.php');
    });
}
```

What the heck am I missing?????

Comment: what version of the framework?

Comment: If you are on version `5.5.7` this is fixed in `5.5.8`.[PR to fix](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/21261)

Comment: Thanks @lagbox .. That was what eventually fixed it for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `composer update` fixed this for me.

Apparently there is an issue in version 5.5.7 of laravel/framework

Update to 5.5.8^ to fix this.+

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/21261